# Why is -1L < 1UL true in C?

Tags: c

I have a question while reading about The C Programming Language.

This book says that `printf("%d", -1L < 1UL)` results in 0 because -1L is promoted to `unsigned long`.

I understood this mechanism. But `printf("%d", (unsigned long)-1L)` prints -1.

As `-1L < 1UL` is false, I thought `(unsigned long)-1L` must be converted to a large integer because of 2's complement notation. But it doesn't. Why?

Comment: You're using the wrong format specifier.

Comment: Is the book "K&R" aka "The C Programming Language"?  If so, you have two words in the wrong order and a missing capital P.

Comment: _"As -1L < 1UL is true[...]"_ but it is not true, like you said earlier...

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I edited post. And I solved this thank to kopecs.

Comment: Feel free to create an answer yourself.

Comment: @kopecs The comparison operator should result in an int. No?

Comment: @Tarik Once UB has been identified, all other explanation attempts become futile.

Comment: @Tarik Specifically the issue is the format specifier in `printf("%d", (unsigned long)-1L)`.

Comment: @kopecs ah, ok. I should have read better :-)